# Smart IP module - how to check what every country sees

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-smart-ip

Unfortunately i don't have too much experience with drupal so please feel free to ask for more information if needed and i will provide.

I am using Drupal 7.34 and i have a module installed called Smart IP. I have different blocks which are shown depending on the users IP/Location/Language.

For example, when editing a block, going to the **Show block on specific pages** -> **Pages on which this PHP Code returns TRUE (experts only)** with the below code :

```
<?php

$smart_ip_session = smart_ip_session_get('smart_ip');
if (isset($smart_ip_session['location']['country_code'])){
        if ($smart_ip_session['location']['country_code'] =='GR' && drupal_is_front_page()){
                    return TRUE;
          }
}
?>
```

The above block will be shown if it's a `drupal_is_front_page())` and if `country_code` is `GR`.

Since i am from Greece, the specific block is going to be loaded. How can i check how the block of another country looks like?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

If you know already how you want this function to behave then use dependence injection to return a mocked version of this object.
This will allow you test the rest of the application using whatever country's settings you like.

**Or,** if it is this function itself you need to test then use a VPN to request the page from another country.
e.g. https://www.operavpn.com/ or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unlimited-free-vpn-hola/gkojfkhlekighikafcpjkiklfbnlmeio
Both free to use.